# What does the surname "Hoerster" mean?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english, person-names

As you can see from my username, my surname is "Hoerster." Before the Hoersters came over to the United States from Prussia, and before that, Germany itself, they spelled their surname as Hörster. Does anyone know what this means?

(I am a Yiddish speaker who is learning a bit of German and I do not think it is Yiddish even though it is a German-Jewish surname.)

**Edit:**

I am also wondering the proper German pronunciation of Hörster. In Texas (where I live), we were taught to pronounce it "Her-ster" but that sounds very botched. How should it really be said?

Comment: It's a field name at a village. *Hörster* is the one who lives on the local *Horst*. See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horst_(Toponym)

Comment: @Janka - Danke schön. That is very interesting. Perhaps this would be a good reason why the Hoersters were successful sheep and cattle raisers. Why did you not make this an answer? Anyways, I look forward to seeing what other users say, even though I'm inclined to say your explanation is the best.

Comment: Attention: I have also added an edit to my question asking for the proper pronunciation.

Comment: The German syllable *hör* sounds like the English word *her*. The -ster is "spiky", as in ster-oids.

Comment: @Janka - So I was taught the correct way of saying it. Fantastic!

Comment: *As you can see from my username* - Your username is *e3ra* :)

Comment: @Bernhard Döbler it used to say Ezra Hoerster :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hörster* is the name of the family living on the *Horst*. This is a formation of the ground, and also a field name at a village. See [the Wikipedia entry on this.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horst_(Toponym))

*Hör-* in *Hörster* ist indeed pronounced as the English word *her*. The -st- is "spiky" as in the English word *steroids*, the final *-er* is a schwa in reality (a hushed *a* sound.)

Comment: The original pronunciation of the -st- does not have to have been "spiky". It depends on what region the name comes from. E.g in the southwestern parts of the German speaking area, where Alleman dialects are spoken, st is always pronunced "sht" regardless of the position in a word. (Ist-ischt, kannst-kannscht) Furthermore, the combination -rst- (as indeed is found in Hörster) is spoken as "sht" in the Bavarian dialects in the southeast. (Wurst-Wurscht, erst-erscht)